# Glassfish 3 Classloader Sequence

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, classpath, classloader

This basic topic still puzzles me. Lets assume I have a library in my deployed war. I have libs in GF/lib and GF/domain/../lib
In which sequence are the libraries read or searched for ?
What happens if I have conflicting jars (eg. SLF4j with diff versions in the above paths)?

We use activemq 5.5.0 which relies on an older SLF4j lib (with log4j) and our web app uses the current SLF4j version (with logback) and keep on bumping into incomp. errors.

Any ideas or explanations ?
Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 1):

The libraries inside application ear/war/jar files are loaded very last, but then within the same folder I haven't found anything yet that details the order.

This has a table of the different library location load orders: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/6niugesfp/index.html#indexterm-28

This talks about a way to control the order within a single library folder: http://www.java.net/node/704037

If you are deploying ActiveMQ yourself, maybe you could unpack the jar and remove the older SLF4J libs?  That way you could bind SLF4J to logback for both parts, too.

Comment: activemq-all-5.5.0.jar contains no jar files as library but the class files. This is unfortunately no option.

Comment: I resolved situation by using the individual files from the activemq package and not using the "all" file