# Eclipselink JPARS exception "ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY not found"

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, derby

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 and Eclipselink 2.4.1 (at least I thought so!) and derby (from Glassfish as JTA resource).

When accessing the Entities in my app via "XXXX:8080/myapp/persistence/, I get the following error. Please note: the "Eclipselink Persistence Service" is reported with version 2.3.2, which looks strange to me, too. I would expect to see my configured version 2.4.1 (see below).

Any ideas?

```
INFO: JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
INFO: [EL Info]: 2013-04-05 17:11:09.876--ServerSession(478107)--file:Server/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/stats/WEB-INF/classes/_onLocal login successful


FINE: An Exception was thrown while creating a JAXBContext for persistence unit [onLocal]: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50055] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: Error creating DynamicJAXBContext: ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY not found in properties map, or map was null.]]
INFO: [EL Info]: 2013-04-05 17:11:10.191--ServerSession(478107)--file:Server/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/tracktron_stats/WEB-INF/classes/_tracktronLocal logout successful

FINE: You are requesting types [[*/*]] from JPA RS.
FINE: exception_marshalling_persitence_unit (There is no English translation for this message.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is the Glassfish version used here (V3.1.2): The project was built with eclipselink 2.4.1, but Glassfish comes with older versions (see log). This was not so easy to fix, but there is another stackoverflow solution that finally worked:

[Glassfish 3 Classloader Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814459/glassfish-3-classloader-sequence)